# Add element to a deep element in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a DOM to which I would like to add an element. The problem here is that I would like to add the element deep in the DOM (in an element with a specific class).

I tried that:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('lm_content')[0].append(iframeDoc)
```

But it doesn't add to the document...

Edit:

Here is my html

```
<div class="lm_goldenlayout lm_item lm_root" style="width: 1280px; height: 511px;">
    <div class="lm_item lm_stack" style="width: 1280px; height: 511px;">
        <div class="lm_header" style="height: 20px; overflow: visible;">
            <ul class="lm_tabs">
                <li class="lm_tab lm_active" title="home" style="z-index: 1;">
                    <i class="lm_left"></i>
                    <span class="lm_title">home</span>
                    <div class="lm_close_tab" style="display: none;">
                    </div>
                    <i class="lm_right"></i>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="lm_controls">
                <div id="plusTab" class="clickable plusTab" style="font-size: 18px;">+</div>
                <li class="lm_close" title="close"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="lm_items" style="width: 1280px; height: 491px;">
            <div class="lm_item_container" style="width: 1280px; height: 491px; display: block;">
                <div class="lm_content" style="width: 1280px; height: 491px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain your usage of the ActionScript tags?

Comment: Have you tried the appendChild() method

Comment: append() is actionscript isn't it?

Comment: appendChild() doesn't work either...

Comment: is that a jquery selector?

Comment: Please show us the relevant HTML.  Also need to know what `lm_content` is and what `iframeDoc` is.  It looks suspiciously like you may be dealing with iframes here where you have to get the contentDocument of the iFrame in order to operate on it's DOM (which is separate from the parent DOM).

Comment: Also, what is your execution environment?  Is this plain Javascript in a browser?  jQuery in a browser?  Or something else?  ActionScript?

Comment: The execution is javascript and jquery in the browser

Comment: Lose the dollar and parenthesis and change `append` to `appendChild` (if `iFrameDoc` is a valid js element)

Comment: iframedoc is an element cut from the body. I tried appendChild() without success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in fact using Jquery.

```
$(".lm_content").append(iframeDoc)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d98vmm15/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) when it's available. Take a try if you love pure Javascript.

```
document.querySelector('.lm_content').appendChild(iframeDoc);
```